# 2010 Lincoln MKS 3.7 V6

Tags: tires, suspension, wheels, lincoln

2010 LINCOLN MKS: Shakes horrible when driving and trying to stop, I’m close to 240,000 miles now but when I’m on smoother roads it’s not as bad. I’m here for an honest opinion because I’ve spent more money than I should have in the past because I’m a woman. I just recently replaced fuses and did my own tune-up, but I’m puzzled that my front end (Left & Right side)is about to break apart and recently my brakes are rough as well now.

Comment: Do you feel it in the steering wheel? If so have the inner tie rods checked. At 240K it could be anything, have it checked by a professional.

Comment: Is it while braking only?

Comment: Being a female of the species has absolutely nothing to do with it. That stereotype has got to go.

Comment: We feel your pain! There are many things that could be going wrong, a bit more information would be helpful. Do the vibrations get worse at higher speeds, or worst with the type of road surface? Does the vibration get much worse when braking, or about the same? Does the car pull in either direction when cruising, or when braking?